# Ant design change default colors

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I tried to change Button text's default color of ant design component . In my table i put transparent LinkButton in each row . This is why my table seems like that . I use Scss i try to change color of name blue to gray . Thank you for every one of you .

```
<Button
style={{ color: 'none !important' }}
className={s['transparent-button']`
>
{original.name }`
```

I tried like that because of Button every text include LinkButton is blue . How can i change color ?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite ant design's styles with your own if the component doesn't support Style props.

```
.ant-btn-primary {
  color: #ebebeb;
}
```